# How to view the packages/tools that will be installed by Ubuntu Make?

Tags: ubuntu-make

e.g. If I use following command:

```
$ umake web
```

How to list all the tools/ide/packages installed by this command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/umake.1.html):

```
* Command 'web': usage: umake web [-h] {visual-studio-code,firefox-dev}
       ...

   positional arguments:
              {visual-studio-code,firefox-dev}

       visual-studio-code
              Visual Studio focused on modern web and cloud

       firefox-dev
              Firefox Developer Edition
```

It looks like only Visual Studio Code and Firefox Developer Edition are installed by `umake web`. The other subcommands are also listed in the manpage, for example:

```
* Command     'android':     usage:     umake     android     [-h]
       {android-ndk,android-sdk,android-studio} ...

   positional arguments:
              {android-ndk,android-sdk,android-studio}

       android-ndk
              Android NDK

       android-sdk
              Android SDK

       android-studio
              Android Studio (default)
```